# Error on import statements while integrating Test Link through WebDriver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, libraries, testlink

I am trying to integrate `TestLink` with `WebDriver` using Java.

So after executing tests in `WebDriver`, results will go to the `TestLink`.

I got some code online but I get error

```
Import br can not be resolved.
```

I have imported following libraries - testlink-api-client-2.0, commons-logging-1.1, ws-commons-util-1.0.2, xmlrpc-client-3.1, xmlrpc-common-3.1-sources.

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Import statements on which I get error:

```
import br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI;
import br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.constants.ExecutionStatus;
import br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.constants.ExecutionType;
import br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.constants.TestCaseDetails;
import br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.model.TestCase;
import br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.TestLinkAPIException;
```

Comment: It looks like for some reason your compiler cannot resolve those imports, which relate to the `testlink` library.  Most likely, the jar for that library is either not on your classpath, or on it twice in different versions.  You need to check your project setup to make sure the compiler can find those jars.

Answer (score 0):

Download the below "testlink-api-client-2.0" jar file and use it. This should solve your problem.

https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/dbfacade-testlink-rpc-api/testlink-api-client-2.0.zip